# How common is the use of "瞧" and which region?

Tags: usage

I've seen [瞧](http://www.nciku.com/search/all/%E7%9E%A7) used every now and then in written Chinese, but I've rarely heard it said in spoken Chinese except for the occasional mention of 瞧不起.

A couple of days ago I was watching [Kung Fu Panda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_Fu_Panda) and it was used often enough in the dialogue that I noticed it.

This had me thinking, do people actually use it in spoken Chinese regularly. Doing a Google search yields plenty of results, so it has me thinking that it must be common, just not within my circle of friends or family. Even with 瞧不起 I am more likely to hear 看不起.

So is it very common in spoken Chinese? If so, is there a specific geographic location that is more likely to use it?

Comment: why not mention 瞅 （iciba：<动> [方] （看） look at ； see） in the same context

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know the people of Beijing and Hebei province often use 瞧,for example:

> 瞧病（go to hospital）
>
> 瞧您说的

In fact,In most north parts of China use 瞧，such as

> 让我瞧瞧（Let me see）

is often heard in Shanxi Province.

It is more often to hear such word in dialect than in mandarin.

Comment: Be aware of one thing--maybe Beijing dialect is very similar to the mandarin,but it's much less formal than mandarin.

Comment: I heard it from a little 3-year-old boy going to a kindergarten in Beijing, so it must be pretty common! The note about Beijing dialect is well taken.

Comment: what does 瞧您说的 mean?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen it used in Taiwan, but never heard anyone actually speak it.
I have seen it as subtitles of western movies or tv series as "你瞧瞧" , meaning "Look at this!"

Answer (score 2):

Yes we use it in spoken Chinese regularly.

Relatively speaking, 瞧 used more colloquially, partly for regional reason.
As said above, heads from north china.

But either are fine, just very tiny distinction. Use 瞧 makes you Chinese more impressive.
=)

Answer (score 1):

等着瞧吧 (you'll see, just wait and see, just you wait, rest assured, etc.) appears to be widely used, iciba has many example sentences containing this phrase.

兔子，等着瞧！Russian: Ну, погоди!, Well, Just You Wait! is a Soviet/Russian animated series produced by Soyuzmultfilm. [兔子，等着瞧！](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%85%94%E5%AD%90%EF%BC%8C%E7%AD%89%E7%9D%80%E7%9E%A7%EF%BC%81)is the logo of each episode and the line pronounced by the wolf after his wicked designs have come to nothing. 本剧的标志，每集的最后狼说的 “Ну, Заяц, ну погоди!"

Answer (score 0):

瞧您说的

How to Translate: Look what you say.

That means: he does not want to directly deny what you have just said, but he feels your remark is a little inapproriate. He does not support what you say and feels that what you say make him embarrased. He used this phrase only to indicate some implied intentions, such as he wanted you to realize your remake is improper.